# Reduce and roots of an irrational inequality

Tags: inequalities

I use command `Reduce` to solve an inequality. First, I used

```
Reduce[Sqrt[4 x + 5] - Sqrt[-6 x + 10] <= Sqrt[2 x - 1], x]
```

and got

> x < -(5/4) || 1/2 <= x <= 1

I put

```
f[x_] := Sqrt[4 x + 5] - Sqrt[-6 x + 10] - Sqrt[2 x - 1]
```

and found $f[-2]$,

> I Sqrt[3] - I Sqrt[5] - Sqrt[22]

That is meant `I Sqrt[3] - I Sqrt[5] - Sqrt[22]<= 0`. I think, this is wrong.

Second, I used

```
Reduce[Sqrt[4 x + 5] - Sqrt[-6 x + 10] <= Sqrt[2 x - 1], x, Reals]
```

I got

> 1/2 <= x <= 1

Is this a bug with `Reduce[Sqrt[4 x + 5] - Sqrt[-6 x + 10] <= Sqrt[2 x - 1], x]`?

Comment: [Please do not use the bugs tag when posting new question.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tags/bugs/info)  It will be added later if deemed appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to leave a comment responding to Szabolcs's tricky example `Reduce[x + Sqrt[-x] < x^2 + Sqrt[-x], x]`, but it's too long so I will leave an answer.

Even adding restrictions to the reals will leave the inequality `x > 1`:

```
Reduce[x + Sqrt[-x] < x^2 + Sqrt[-x] && x ∈ Reals, x, Reals]
```

> ```
> x < 0 || x > 1
> ```

If you want to be as careful and meticulous as possible, you can restrict your inequality to the domain of the lhs and rhs.

```
CarefulRealReduce[head_[f_, g_], x_] := Reduce[head[f, g] && 
  FunctionDomain[f, x, Method -> {Reduce -> False}] && 
  FunctionDomain[g, x, Method -> {Reduce -> False}], x]

CarefulRealReduce[x + Sqrt[-x] < x^2 + Sqrt[-x], x]
```

> ```
> x < 0
> ```

```
CarefulRealReduce[Sqrt[4 x + 5] - Sqrt[-6 x + 10] <= Sqrt[2 x - 1], x]
```

> ```
> 1/2 <= x <= 1
> ```

Comment: And this works for the OP's example too.  Using the domain `Reals` feels uncomfortable because of things like the *casus irreducibilis*.

Comment: @Szabolcs That is a very good point. Determining what is real is not just as simple as looking for the imaginary unit in the expression. Another subtle thing is symbolic expressions like `ArcSin[2]` are not real, yet the imaginary unit does not appear.

Answer (score 0):

If you specify the domain `Reals`, the problem goes away:

```
Reduce[Sqrt[4 x + 5] - Sqrt[-6 x + 10] <= Sqrt[2 x - 1], x, Reals]
(* 1/2 <= x <= 1 *)
```

The problem region, `x < -5/4`, is where both expressions contain an imaginary part, so we should have discarded it anyway.

Comment: Yes, my understanding is that the question is about why `x < -5/4` is returned and whether it is a bug.  An inequality should implicitly assume that both sides are real.  But then there are some edge cases that require a bit more thought before hastily declaring them a bug, even if strictly mathematically they're incorrect ... e.g. what about `Reduce[x + Sqrt[-x] < x^2 + Sqrt[-x], x]`?  It says `x < 0 || x > 1`. But for `x>1`, both sides have imaginary components ... which do cancel out.

Comment: @Szabolcs I wouldn't call either of these cases a bug, they're just examples of undefined behavior.  Mathematica can manipulate the inequality however it wants internally, and will do so assuming the arguments are real, even if the arguments may actually be complex.  To get defined behavior, we have to tell Mathematica to watch for possible complex numbers by using the domain `Reals`, or by limiting `x` to the range where the inequality makes sense, e.g. by adding `&& x > 1/2`.

Comment: What `Reals` does is that it assumes that *all* subexpressions are real, at least according to the documentation (which often simplifies things).  This makes things much simpler because it needs to restrict each of `Sqrt[4 x + 5]`, `Sqrt[-6 x + 10]` and `Sqrt[2 x - 1]` to be real *separately*.    I still don't understand where `x < -5/4` comes from and it *is* clearly a wrong answer.  Do you understand how it arrives to this wrong result?  (Other than the fact that `4x+5` changes sign at that value.)

Comment: @Szabolcs `x < -5/4` makes sense as an answer, but only the developers can tell you why.  It's just an example of GIGO: if you give an inequality whose arguments may be complex, you shouldn't expect any result at all.